# Admob is crashing but very rare

Tags: ios, exception, crash, admob

Usually my iOS app works fine. But sometimes it crashes.
I attached screenshot. I called functions to show admob interstitial.
It crashed. 
I am not sure how to debug it and why it crashed that time.
That code works fine most of time but rarely crashes.

My app uses ARC.

It is iphone Open GL ES 2.0 game with Admob and iAd

How do I debug it? 
What steps should be done?

I am not sure when I will see such crash next time.
Crashes happen but not often. So If I will remove some components like iAd and will test then I do not know when it will crash and how many tests to run to ensure that removed part was coursing a problem or not.

I do not wish to submit app that sometime crashes. It may course bad reviews.

[image: xcode screenshot]

UPDATE for crashes

@try/@catch is not helping.

delegate update is not helping either.

I got such crash again and have no idea what I can do or what is coursing it.

[image: ss xcode]

[image]

Comment: The disassembly appears to come from the app running in the simulator.   What happens with a real device?

Comment: Sometimes it also crashes when interstitial should be shown on device. I do not yet have screenshot of stack trace. Usually it is first run after install. I check `isReady` property before showing interstitial.

Comment: There is some information that is missing here, in particular the reason for the crash. That information is probably in the debugging console or crash log. You should try to find that information and post it in your question.

Comment: It does not happen so often that I can reproduce immediately. On screenshot it shows `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` and address that is not nil. I could imagine that it is freed object but I use `ARC` and I do not `release` / `retain` myself. lldb had regular logged data. Nothing extra. What else I can check in debugging console?

Comment: Along with the crash there will be information in the Xcode debug console.

Comment: I updated. There is nothing in debug console that may help.

Comment: After more than 1 year, I am seeing similar problem as you did for Admob interstitial's video ad. Have you found a solution yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap that call with try/catch.

Comment: This will **NOT** help! The app is trying to access an invalid object, see the `obj_msgSend` above on the of the stack trace. Exception catching doesn't do a thing in that case.

Comment: Actually it helped. It was not catching it in catch block but started printing in debug console. (ADBannerView: no delegate or delegate does not implement didFailToReceiveAdWithError:”) ADBannerView not GADBannerView. ADBannerView is iAd. My delegate had implementation for both Admob and iAd. But iAd was not used right now directly but with mediation. When I removed ADBannerViewDelegate impl. from delegate that I pass to Admob then it started to work. Seems like it was crashing when system was trying to call  iAds didFailToReceiveAdWithError. But was not logging until I added try/catch.

Comment: I will wait a bit as and if there would be no other ideas I will mark it as response.

Comment: Kemi! You are right. I got repeated crash. I updated screenshots. There is not information that may help.